# Azure Map with Angular 5

Tags: angular5, azure-maps

I am trying to use Azure Map in Angular 5. I am getting below error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'azure-maps-control' in 'D:\projects\ng5\azure-map\src\app\components\app-map'".

I have 1.3.8 version of azure-maps-control installed. My component.ts file

`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as atlas from 'azure-maps-control';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-map',
  templateUrl: './app-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-map.component.css']
})
export class AppMapComponent implements OnInit {
  map;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
      center: [-122.33, 47.6],
      zoom: 12,
      language: 'en-US',
      authOptions: {
          authType: 'subscriptionKey',
          subscriptionKey: '<Subscriptyion Key>'
      }
    });
  }

}
```

`

I have created index.d.ts file where i am declaring azure map module like
`declare module 'azure-maps-control';`

I have already added css and js file in index.html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/azure-maps-control/dist/atlas.min.css" type="text/css"> 
<script src="node_modules/azure-maps-control/dist/atlas.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following;

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as azMaps from 'azure-maps-control';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-map',
  templateUrl: './app-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-map.component.css']
})
export class AppMapComponent implements OnInit {
  map;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.map = new azMaps.Map('myMap', {
      center: [-122.33, 47.6],
      zoom: 12,
      language: 'en-US',
      authOptions: {
          authType: azMaps.AuthenticationType.subscriptionKey,
          subscriptionKey: '<Subscription Key>'
      }
    });
  }

}
```

As an example, there is an open source project written in TypeScript that uses Azure Maps here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-maps-services-ui

Comment: No luck. Still same error. Am I supposed to install others library also? Or azure-maps-control is not supportable with Angular 5.

Comment: Azure Maps control is based on vanilla JavaScript and HTML, so should work in any web app.

Comment: Take a look at the console and network tabs of dev tools and make sure that the JaveScript and CSS files are being loaded. Unless you are embedding this in a mobile web app, I recommend pointing to the CDN hosted files rather than the files in the node_module folder. 

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.js"></script>```

Also make sure to have something like `<div id="myMap"></div>` in your HTML file of the component.

Comment: I just downloaded and modified this Angular 5 app https://github.com/SibeeshVenu/ng5 and managed to get the Azure Maps control to work pretty easily.

Comment: Hi, I have changed the script and css url pointing to CDN hosted file. And simple import 
`import * as atlas from azure-maps-control`
I am getting below error "ERROR in node_modules/azure-maps-control/typings/index.d.ts(4195,47): error TS1110: Type expected."

You can clone code from https://github.com/MayurGIS/azure-map.git

Comment: Looks like your TypeScript build doesn't like the use of "any" which is used for Expressions. This is the code that your linter doesn't like `export type Expression = [ExpressionName, ...any[]];` The expression code is fairly complex and constantly evolving, so we use "any".

Comment: Taking a closer look it appears it doesn't like the array itself because a type isn't defined outside of if. If I change that one line to this it works: `export type Expression = any[]`, but that is less helpful from the intellisense side of things.

Comment: Actually, now it looks like it doesn't like the `...` which is odd, as that is pretty standard notation. I'm not able to reproduce this outside of your app, so not sure which setting is causing this.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Some setting is causing this as you mentioned.